# Elasticsearch nested mapping does not seem to work

Tags: elasticsearch

Given the following document,

```
{
  "domain": "www.example.com",
  "tag": [
    {
      "name": "IIS"
    },
    {
      "name": "Microsoft ASP.NET"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I launch a query for `asp` or `asp.net` I would like to see the `Microsoft ASP.NET` document in the result set.

So I need a lower case analyzer and remove the `.` character from word delimiters, so I tried the following mapping,

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/tag-test -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "domain_filter": {
                    "type": "word_delimiter",
                    "type_table": [". => ALPHANUM", ": => ALPHANUM"]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "domain_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "domain_filter"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "assets": {
            "properties": {
                "domain": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "domain_analyzer"
                },
                "tag": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "domain_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'; echo
```

Then I tried the following queries, all of which yield an empty result

```
tag.name:asp
tag.name:asp.net
tag.name:*asp*
```

I'm using querystring query,

```
curl http://localhost:9200/tag-test/_search?q=tag.name:asp
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you reindexed the documents after new settings upload?

Comment: What type of query are you running. I mean `term`, `querystring' , 'match`???

Comment: @xeye the index is deleted and recreated everytime

Comment: @Richa querystring query, something like `curl xxx:9200/xxxx/_search?q=xxxxx`

Comment: Did you also try a [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the `query_string` query doesn't have support for nested queries and **unless** your use `include_in_parent: true` (which will flatten the `nested` field in an array in the parent document) in your mapping, the query_string will not work ever.

Secondly, with your analyzer you will have `asp.net` as a term being indexed in Elasticsearch. Which means the `query_string` will work with `tag.name:asp.net` and `tag.name:*asp*`. I recommend **not to use a leading wildcard** though.

So, in the end your test should be:

```
PUT /tag-test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "domain_filter": {
          "type": "word_delimiter",
          "type_table": [
            ". => ALPHANUM",
            ": => ALPHANUM"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "domain_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "domain_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "assets": {
      "properties": {
        "domain": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "domain_analyzer"
        },
        "tag": {
          "type": "nested",
          "include_in_parent": true,
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "domain_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice `"include_in_parent": true` in the mapping for `tag`.
Then the query should be:

- `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/tag-test/_search?q=tag.name:asp*"`
- `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/tag-test/_search?q=tag.name:asp.net"`

Comment: Thanks Andrei! It works, I use `*` only to make query strings like `tag.name:micro*` to work (To find `Microsoft ASP.NET` with `micro` does not work), should I use ngram to accomplish that?

Comment: What I meant was **leading** wildcard :-) (meaning `*net`). That's very costly. `nGram` are another way, yes. You need to test the performance and see which suits you better.